# How to get merge request stats using Git CLI command?

Tags: gitlab, git

I needed to get the final stats on a sample Merge Request with multiple commits on it.
I have tried pulling in `git ls-remote origin 'refs/merge-requests/*/head'` then trying to get insertion and deletion but not sure how to get the final cumulative Merge request files changed along with lines count removed or added. Also, if MR is open or closed or merged status, if possible.

Please suggest.

Comment: Does this pertain to github or gitlab? Can we remove one or both of the tags??